# Does single quote behave the same as it does in Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby

I start exploring the fundation of Ruby, it is the C,

```
printf('%%\\');
```

Does the code above allowed in C?

Comment: what happens when you try this out?

Comment: BTW this is easy to try out.  Sites like ideone.com and codepad.org will let you type in and (try to) compile programs in C, and dozens of other languages.

Comment: FYI " the fundation of Ruby, it is the C" is not English, and is too far from English to figure out what it means. "Does the code above allowed in C?" is understandable, but should be "Is the code ...". ... On second thought, I guess you're saying that C is the foundation of Ruby, but that's not true ... or very distantly true.

Comment: I had tried the code under the linux and gcc compiler, I just can't interpret the errors generated from the compiler.

Comment: @JimBalter Sorry about the English

Comment: sorry about asking this question,  Now it's weekend in the campus and now in the enrollment process, I bearly have person to ask and resources to figure out the information, not lazy enough to try the code out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code is not allowed.

In Ruby single quotes are used to write string literals, i.e. values of type string. In C `'%%\\'` has the type int. Since `printf` expects a string (`char*`) as its first argument, `'%%\\'` is not a valid first argument to `printf`.

Comment: The meaning of '%%\\' is implementation-defined.

Comment: so fancinating, now I know single quote is only for single character 'a' , for the  In C '%%\\' has the type int part which is still quite get yet. How can I inspect the datatype of '%%//', is there any way like '%%//'.class or '%%//'.type in C?

Comment: @yozloy There is no way to inspect types at runtime, but if you actually try to do `printf('bla')`, you'll get a warning telling you that you supplied an integer to a function that takes a char*. So that's how you can know that 'bla' is an int (that or reading the standard or a book/tutorial about C - C isn't really designed for learning it by experimentation).

Comment: Also note that single quotes can contain more than just a single character - otherwise writing '%%\\' would have been a syntax error. However, as Jim already pointed out, the value of an integer character literal containing multiple characters is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        printf('%%\\');
        return 0;
}
```

6 lines. Please just try it next time.
It produces a runtime error.

So no, it's not allowed. Did you really have to ask this?

I recommend ideone and codepad to test things out quickly if you don't want to do it locally/don't have a compiler at hand/whatever other reason.

EDIT:

Seeing the other answer, I think that I should note that

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        printf("%d", '%%\\');
        return 0;
}
```

is perfectly fine and prints 2434396.
I just don't want you to get idea that single quotes are illegal.

Comment: It may print that with *your* compiler, but the meaning of '%%\\' is implementation-defined.

Comment: As are many, many things and naming the differences between implementations with every question, especially with such an entry-level question is this is going pretty off-topic, unless it doesn't produce the same result for OP. I guess I should have mentioned it though, sorry.

Comment: There are not "many, many things" that are implementation-defined, but multi-char constants are, and yes, such things should be mentioned so people aren't confused when they don't get the same result. Remember that SO questions are not just for the person who asked the question, they are for everyone.

Comment: +1 for "SO questions are not just for the person who asked the question, they are for everyone" .. very true

Comment: `several_chracters_as_number.c:4:5: warning: multi-character
      character constant [-Wmultichar]
a = '\\%';`